# Merging ffdf dataframes in R

Tags: r, ffbase, ff

I need an outer join of ffdf dataframes saved in a list. Have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373109/merging-and-appending-ffdf-dataframes), but it refers to a different problem. Example code for RAM objects:

```
x1 = data.frame(name='a1', Ai=2, Ac=1, Bi=1)
x2 = data.frame(name='a2', Ai=1, Bi=3, Bc=1, Ci=1)
x3 = data.frame(name='a3', Ai=3, Ac=2, Bi=2, Ci=3, Cc=1, Di=2, Dc=2)
x4 = data.frame(name='a4', Ai=3, Bi=2, Ci=1, Fi=2)
dl = list(x1,x2,x3,x4)
mergedDF = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), dl)
mergedDF[is.na(merged.data.frame)] = 0
```

Desired result looks like:

```
mergedDF
  name Ai Bi Ci Ac Bc Cc Di Dc Fi
1   a1  2  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
2   a2  1  3  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
3   a3  3  2  3  2  0  1  2  2  0
4   a4  3  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

As long as I turn the data frames to ffdf though, I get the error

```
Error in merge.ffdf(..., all = T) : merge.ffdf only allows inner joins
```

Any known workrounds? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. The development version of ffbase contains a function called `ffdfrbind.fill` (similar as rbind.fill). `library(devtools);
install_github("edwindj/ffbase", subdir="pkg")` will install that development version. Normally ffdfrbind.fill(x1, x2, x3, x4) will get you there.

Comment: rbind.fill functionality is what is needed indeed. Unfortunately I get this error when I try `install_github("edwindj/ffbase", subdir="pkg")` : `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ffbase'`

Comment: I believe you are working on windows. If you want to install the package from source as is done with install_github, you need to have Rtools installed. Do you have Rtools installed? http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: `Warning message: package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)`

Comment: Is Rtools in your path. Maybe you need to restart your computer before it is in your path?

Comment: Managed to install it, still function `ffdfrbind.fill` is missing :-(

Comment: A right, it is not in the namespace yet. You can access it for the time being as `ffbase:::ffdfrbind.fill`. At the next releas of ffbase, you can remove the `ffbase:::` part

Comment: Awesome as usual. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped me [Combine two data frames by rows (rbind) when they have different sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/rbind-different-number-of-columns). So to do a similar thing with yours:

```
   install.packages('plyr')
   require(plyr)
   answer <- Reduce(rbind.fill,dl)
   answer[is.na(answer)] <- 0
   answer

  name Ai Ac Bi Bc Ci Cc Di Dc Fi
1   a1  2  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2   a2  1  0  3  1  1  0  0  0  0
3   a3  3  2  2  0  3  1  2  2  0
4   a4  3  0  2  0  1  0  0  0  2
```

BTW nice thought with `Reduce`, that's a nifty little function that rarely (at least for me) gets used.